# Recuperate image from DATABASE

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I'm trying to recuperate image from my database and show it on my website, I'm working with Laravel and whenever I try to do that as for example on my view:

```
 @foreach($users as $users)
     <tr>
         <td >{{$users ->id}}</td>
         <td >{{$users ->name}}</td>
         <td >{{$users ->email}}</td>
         <td>{{$users ->photo}}</td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

It only shows me the url of my photo, and it's exactly what I stocked in my DB

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: you probably want to put the photo url into the `img` tag

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: @sjaustirni Can you tell me how to do that??

Comment: You don't close you `<tr>`. It does not solve the problem but it is not very clean.

Comment: @jarlh Dont we need sql requests to have an interaction with DB ?

Comment: @H.tay Do you know HTML? It's pretty essential for your job I'd say. Here's a quick intro to HTML images. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: @Meloman Even after I close it ,I just have a list of information and I didn't want all the data to be pasted, I must've forgotten to close it here while pasting it, my problem is exacly on  <td>{{$users ->photo}}</td>

Comment: @sjaustirni I don't think this has something to do with HTML, I know HTML but i think it's more about PHP Script

Comment: Based on your description, no, this is an HTML thing. Try to do this: `<td><img src="{{$users ->photo}}"></td>`

Comment: @sjaustirni I tried it, still it doesnt helpl :/

Comment: `@foreach($users as $users)` should probably be `@foreach($users as $user)` note the lack of the s. and then use `{{$user->photo}}` again without the s while iterating

Comment: @Mike I tried exactly what you said, there is still no result,

Comment: @H.tay Well then i think you have not provided enough information for us to help you find a solution. Maybe you can update the question with more information. For example what does the controller / model look like.

Comment: It's clearly a html problem, SQL have nothing to do with that. Based on what you said you should use a `<img>` html tag but you said it's not working. Where did you store your image ? What's the url of your image ? How did you store your image in your database ? We can't guess what you do... Your foreach should be like @Mike said.

Comment: Show us your result after foreach cycle, inside td element what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Right code here:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
     <tr>
         <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
         <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
         <td><img src="{{ url($user->photo) }}" witdh="40px" height="40px"></td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

The photo is not in db. but in a folder.
In DB there is the URL to fetch the images.